# How to access application arguments in log4j.properties file?

Tags: apache-spark, logging, log4j, log4j2

I'm working on a legacy project which uses log4j.properties file for logging configuration. In the properties file I'm trying to access the system variables (or application arguments) in the following manner-

```
log4j.appender.consoleapp.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %d{Z} [%t] %-5p (%F:%L) - %m%n BUCKET_ID=${sys:BUCKET_ID:-default_id}

# logs are getting generated like-
# 2016-05-14 00:34:11,994 +0530 [main] WARN  (Log4jExample.java:20) - My Warn Log BUCKET_ID=
```

But I'm **unable** to get BUCKET_ID value even though BUCKET_ID is an application argument that I provided. I've also tried substituting the variable as BUCKET_ID=${BUCKET_ID} but in vain.

Update : Maybe I should have mentioned this earlier but its a spark application in Java. I know spark only supports log4j. I'm adding the properties file through -Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.properties and it is getting picked but the BUCKET_ID is not getting set in logs even though I'm passing BUCKET_ID as extrajavaoptions in driver and executer configuration.

Comment: What do you mean by application argument? Do you mean a `-DBUCKET_ID=foobar` argument to the `java` command?

Comment: No, I'm passing it as --BUCKET_ID=foobar but I tried -DBUCKET_ID=foobar and it still didn't work

Answer (score 1):

The [system property lookup](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html#system-properties-lookup) is a feature of Log4j version 2.

Spark comes packaged with the [Log4j 1.x bridge](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html#option-1-use-the-log4j-1-x-bridge-log4j-1-2-api) and this bridge is activated when a legacy configuration file like `log4j.properties` is found. This means that you cannot use the lookups inside of `log4j.properties`.

But even in Log4j 1.x you can use JVM system properties, e.g. everything that you have set with `-Dprop=val`. So you can change the entry in `log4j.properties` to

```
log4j.appender.consoleapp.layout.ConversionPattern= [...] BUCKET_ID=${BUCKET_ID}
```

and then you provide the value with `-DBUCKET_ID=${BUCKET_ID}` or via `extraJavaOptions`, depending on your setup.